# Trying to understand variables... can I print them?

Tags: python, theano

If we use one of the tutorial examples:

```
>>> a, b = T.dmatrices('a', 'b')
>>> diff = a - b
>>> f = function([a, b], [diff])
>>>> f([[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[0, 1], [2, 3]])
[array([[ 1.,  0.],
        [-1., -2.]]),
```

Does `diff` now hold the array `[[ 1.,  0.],[-1., -2.]]`?

How can I print out `diff` after my call yo `f()`?

I'm having trouble understanding this functional style of usage. Can anyone explain?

Comment: You can generally print a variable using `print`, or if you're in the Python shell (which you are), just type variable name at the `>>>` prompt and press RETURN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're hitting the most difficult conceptual challenge of learning Theano.

To answer your specific questions first,

1. No, `diff` does not hold the array `[[ 1.,  0.],[-1., -2.]]`. As far as Python is concerned `diff` is a reference to a Theano object. That object is a symbolic variable and never, itself, has or holds a value.
2. When you ask how to print out `diff`, I take that to mean "how can I print out the result of the computation that `diff` is a reference to?" Well, in one sense, you're already doing it: `diff` is the output of the Theano function `f` so after `f` is compiled and then executed via `f([[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[0, 1], [2, 3]])` you see the result is `[array([[ 1.,  0.], [-1., -2.]])`.

What's difficult is separating the symbolic world from the concrete/executable world. `diff` exists in the symbolic world and so doesn't really ever have a value. Everything that happens after compiling `f` via `theano.function(...)` is in the concrete/executable world. With some caveats, nothing in the symbolic world is affected by what happens in the concrete/executable world.

It's also important to note that `diff` cannot "have a value" (in any sense) until the symbolic variables on which it depends, `a` and `b` have been given a value. If I posed a mathematics problem, telling you that `y = x * z` and asked you what value `y` has, you couldn't answer unless I also told you what value `x` and `z` have. The same is true here, the symbolic world operates like symbolic mathematics: it is an abstract definition of some computation that doesn't and can't have a value until compiled and input values are provided.

When developing Theano code it can be helpful to separate the symbolic code from the concrete/executable code into two separate areas. Without doing this you will often find, for example, wanting to call a symbolic variable `x` but then also wanting to give a concrete value that is to be provided for `x` the same name.

Comment: Thanks. This does indeed seem to be the bottleneck in my understanding of theano. So calling `f([[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[0, 1], [2, 3]])` calculate the difference between those two matrices and shows them on my screen. But the result of that computation is not actually stored anywhere after that? I can't "retrieve" the result without calling `f([[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[0, 1], [2, 3]])` again?

Comment: After compilation, the Theano function is just like a normal Python function. You can do `c = f(<inputs>)` and then `c` will be a reference to a numpy array containing the result, i.e. the concrete manifestation of the value that `diff` represents symbolically.

Answer (score 0):

We can not print a symbolic var since it remembers no real value.

However, if you claim diff to be a shared var, u can do the following:
print diff.get_value()

Comment: You're right that a shared variable's value can be obtained that way but we know `diff` isn't a shared variable because it is the symbolic result of subtracting `b` from `a`.

Answer (score -1):

In the console, just type the var name

```
>>> diff
```

In Python 2, use `print diff`, and in Python 3, use `print(diff)`

Comment: I believe this is more of a Theano question than a Python question. Printing diff will not show anything helpful because it is a Theano symbolic variable and doesn't have a concrete value.